# How to create gradient magnitude image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am given a grayscale image and I would like to create gradient magnitude image from it.
I know there is a function called `imgradient`, but I have no idea of how to modify the magnitude so that it is computed the following way:

```
∇f ≈ abs(z7+ 2z8+ z9- z1- 2z2- z3) + abs(z3+ 2z6+ z9- z1- 2z4- z7)
```

Comment: I don't understand the equation that you have posted. Also why do you need to "modify" the magnitude returned by `imgradient`?

Comment: i know they have implement several method, i would just like to know how to implement for the custom method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to implement your own gradient function, and apply it to each pixel in the image I:

```
//example of a 4x5 image I
I = [1 3 2 6 5; 6 1 0 18 21; 13 12 13 14 11; 16 15 28 9 20]

G = I; //set your gradient matrix to be equal to I so that the sides have a value

//get the height and width of image I
[h, w] = size(I);

//loop through each pixel that is not on the side
for x=2:w-1
   for y=2:h-1
      //for each pixel:
      z1 = I(y-1, x-1); //e.g z1 is the pixel on the upper left
      z2 = I(y, x-1);
      z3 = I(y+1, x-1);
      z4 = I(y-1, x);
      z6 = I(y+1, x);
      z7 = I(y-1, x+1);
      z8 = I(y, x+1);
      z9 = I(y+1, x+1);
      G(y,x) =  abs(z7+ 2*z8+ z9- z1- 2*z2- z3) + abs(z3+ 2*z6+ z9- z1- 2*z4- z7);
   end    
end
```

Comment: It almost works perfectly. I have to init a double matrix to store the value. wtf

Answer (score 1):

I get that you want to do spatial filtering using sobel mask (as per your equation). So, I suggest you to use following command: BW = edge(I,'Sobel');

Or If you want exact output as per equation given by you then try this:

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
I = padarray(I,[1 1],'symmetric');
sobel_mask_x = [-1 -2 -1; 0 0 0; 1 2 1];
sobel_x = filter2(sobel_mask_x ,I);
sobel_mask_y = sobel_mask_x';
sobel_y = filter2(sobel_mask_y ,I);
sobel_responce = abs(sobel_x)+abs(sobel_y);
figure,imshow(sobel_responce,[]); title('Sobel gradient');
```

This is faster instead of using for loops.

Comment: L1 gradient magnitude, that you don't see very often :)